# How should one find an angle of a head with respect to the camera?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, geometry

I am working on a project which requires me to find the angle between the person's body w.r.t. the camera. I already have the pose coordinates of the person but I am not sure how to find the angle. Do you think I need to use some camera parameters such as focal length and Intrinsic parameters of the camera? I would appreciate your suggestions or any references.  Thank you.

[image] The circle in the center is the person's head and the camera on the other side

Answer (score 2):

Try this link: https://www.learnopencv.com/head-pose-estimation-using-opencv-and-dlib/

To make long story short, you have to know the 3D coordinates of some points of the person and its 2D projections on the camera sensor plane and then use a PnP (Perspective-n-Point) alghoritm to estimate camera pose relative to the person. It is better to know the calibration of the camera, but you can use the DLT (Direct Linear Transform) alghoritm if you don't have this data.

Comment: Could you please tell me whether humaPose with 18keypoints enough for finding the angle? If I consider the eye coordinates or some of the other joint coordinates to find the angle? I already have the humanPose model.

Comment: In most cases it is enough. Minimum required number of 2D-3D correspondences is 4. So 18 is enough but it may give you inaccurate results if all the points are populated only on a small part of an image or are more or less collinear on the image. 
Secondly, you have to ensure that all of the 2D-3D correspondences are right (for instance that you have correctly identified the corner of an eye). If you are not sure you can use RANSAC to eliminate outliers.
So in general - yes it is enough.